# Reinstalling Rad Studio 2007

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I need to uninstall and re-install Delphi 2007.

I have downloaded the CodeGearRADStudio2007_Dec2007.iso and burned it to disc.

I have exported the following registry keys:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\BDS\5.0\Known Packages
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\BDS\5.0\GExperts-1.3
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\BDS\5.0\Experts

Is there anything else I need to do before uninstalling ?  I'm not sure if uninstaller is going to ask me to preserve registry keys so I assume that I am going to have to import registry keys after installing.

I am also assuming that the iso image contains any previous updates or hotfixes and that is the latest complete install, is that a correct assumption ?

Very nervous about doing this, any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

John

Comment: The place from where you downloaded the iso file should state if it includes any updates.

Comment: Yes, the dec 2007 iso seems to be the last complete iso. There is an apr-08 hotfix exe as well.

Comment: And a May 2008 Help Update. The uninstaller will not remove registry entries (it never even mentions them, IIRC), but I always export them  first just to be safe. I also make a backup copy of the `C:\ProgramData\CodeGear` folder, as that's where the license keys are stored. They'll work even on a new machine, as long as the computer name stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd do is making an image backup of the system partition (e.g. with CloneZilla), including the working Delphi installation. Then, restore that backup to a new hard disk an check that it boots. After that, you can always go back to your previous installation and look up any settings you might have missed.